# Non-canonical re-ordering of nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have some data in the form:

```
 data = {{{d, 0.68}, {g, 0.88}, {h, 0.23}, {e, 0.15}, {b, 0.46}, {a, 0.07}}, 
         {{d, 0.86}, {c, 0.99}, {b, 0.21}}, 
         {{c,0.83}, {h, 0.63}, {f, 0.11}}, 
         {{d, 0.31}, {g, 0.65}, {e, 0.88}, {a, 0.70}}, 
         {{d, 0.58}, {g, 0.09}, {c, 0.66}, {b, 0.18}, {a, 0.15}}}
```

These data are essentially related to each other in the following way:

```
{{{d, d1}, {g, g1}, {h, h1}, {e, e1}, {b, b1}, {a, a1}}, 
 {{d, d2}, {c, c2}, {b, b2}}, 
 {{c, c3}, {h, h3}, {f, f3}}, 
 {{d, d4}, {g, g4}, {e, e4}, {a, a4}}, 
 {{d, d5}, {g, g5}, {c, c5}, {b, b5}, {a, a5}}}
```

The ordering of elements within each second level list is:

```
order1 = {d, g, c, h, e, f, b, a}
```

I want to collect the second term of each third level pair and rearrange the elements according to a different order:

```
order2 = {b, h, d, a, e, f, c, g}
```

so that I end up with something like:

```
{{b1, h1, d1, a1, e1, f1, c1, g1},
 {b2, h2, d2, a2, e2, f2, c2, g2},
 {b3, h3, d3, a3, e3, f3, c3, g3},
 {b4, h4, d4, a4, e4, f4, c4, g4},
 {b5, h5, d5, a5, e5, f5, c5, g5}}
```

Where an element is missing I want to replace it with a zero to obtain rows of equal length. Using numbers it would look like:

```
  {{0.46, 0.23, 0.68, 0.07, 0.15, 0, 0, 0.88}, 
   {0.21, 0, 0.86, 0, 0, 0, 0.99, 0}, 
   {0, 0.63, 0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0.83, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0.31, 0.7, 0.88, 0, 0, 0.65}, 
   {0.18, 0, 0.58, 0.15, 0, 0, 0.66, 0.09}}
```

I am currently using

```
 (row = #; 
   Map[(ordi = #; k = Flatten[Position[row, _?((ordi == #) &)]];
             If[Length[k] == 0, 0, row[[k[[1]], 2]]]) & , order2]) &/@ data
```

**Edit**

The code in the original question is now working... (thanks @partial81 for trying it - and sorry for the confusion).

However, I am still interested in discovering different ways to get the result. Any alternative suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If I use your data and in your approach `order1` (instead of `order`, I get back your shown result (`{{0.68,0.88,...}}`). Also if I use `{{{d, d1}, {g, g1},...}` and `order2` in your approach, I get back something like `{{b1, h1, d1, a1, e1, 0, 0, g1},...}`. So I would say, your solution works. Or aren`t this the results you want to have?

Comment: @partial81 indeed. the code seems to be working. see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another version which involves converting the data into a list of rules:

```
order2 /. Apply[Rule, data, {2}] /. Alternatives @@ order2 -> 0.
```

Comment: Bravo. `AbsoluteTiming` -> _0.000134_ . Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your can do it by converting your data into a list of rules.

```
data = 
{
  {{d, 0.68}, {g, 0.88}, {h, 0.23}, {e, 0.15}, {b, 0.46}, {a, 0.07}}, 
  {{d, 0.86}, {c, 0.99}, {b, 0.21}}, {{c, 0.83}, 
  {h, 0.63}, {f, 0.11}}, {{d, 0.31}, {g, 0.65}, {e, 0.88}, 
  {a, 0.70}}, {{d, 0.58}, {g, 0.09}, {c, 0.66}, {b, 0.18}, {a, 0.15}}
};

default = {#, 0.} & /@ {b, h, d, a, e, f, c, g};

rules = Map[({#[[1]], 0.} -> {#[[1]], #[[2]]}) &, data, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{d, 0.} -> {d, 0.68}, {g, 0.} -> {g, 0.88}, {h, 0.} -> {h, 0.23},  
>    {e, 0.} -> {e, 0.15}, {b, 0.} -> {b, 0.46}, {a, 0.} -> {a, 0.07}},  
>   {{d, 0.} -> {d, 0.86}, {c, 0.} -> {c, 0.99}, {b, 0.} -> {b, 0.21}},  
>    {{c, 0.} -> {c, 0.83}, {h, 0.} -> {h, 0.63}, {f, 0.} -> {f, 0.11}},  
>   {{d, 0.} -> {d, 0.31}, {g, 0.} -> {g, 0.65}, {e, 0.} -> {e, 0.88},  
>    {a, 0.} -> {a, 0.7}}, 
>   {{d, 0.} -> {d, 0.58}, {g, 0.} -> {g, 0.09}, {c, 0.} -> {c, 0.66},  
>    {b, 0.} -> {b, 0.18}, {a, 0.} -> {a, 0.15}}}
> ```

```
Map[Last, Table[default /. r, {r, rules}], {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{0.46, 0.23, 0.68, 0.07, 0.15, 0., 0., 0.88},  
>   {0.21, 0., 0.86, 0., 0., 0., 0.99, 0.},  
>   {0., 0.63, 0., 0., 0., 0.11, 0.83, 0.},  
>   {0., 0., 0.31, 0.7, 0.88, 0., 0., 0.65},  
>   {0.18, 0., 0.58, 0.15, 0., 0., 0.66, 0.09}}
> ```

Comment: nice answer. thanks!